# Choosing an Architecture for XML Annotation with Multi-Element Text Highlighting

Tags: xml, data-structures

I am currently working on a project where I need to annotate XML documents by highlighting specific text fragments. The challenge is that the target text might span across multiple XML elements, and I'm seeking advice on the best architecture for handling this scenario.

**Context:**

Consider the following XML structure:

```xml
<root>
  <p id="1">These delicious oranges</p>
  <p id="2">Have a vibrant color</p>
</root>
```

I need to highlight the text "oranges have a vibrant" across both

elements.

**Possible Approaches:**

- **Invisible Tags for Highlighting**:
  Embed invisible tags directly within the text, indicating the start and end of the highlighted fragment, e.g. `<highlight id="1" start="1">` and `<highlight id="1" end="1">`.
- **Separate Metadata for Annotations**:
  Create a separate metadata structure, associating each XML element with metadata specifying the IDs of the characters to be highlighted, similar to the approach of assigning IDs to characters in each node.

I am seeking advice on the most suitable architecture for this task. What are the pros and cons of the two approaches mentioned above, and are there alternative methods I should consider?

**Additional Information:**

- The XML documents may undergo regular updates and edits.
- Handling potential conflicts during edits to the XML and metadata (change text, remove/insert paragrapsm etc.).

Any insights or recommendations on choosing the right architecture or suggesting alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: StackOverflow discourages questions about design and application architecture: the focus is on coding.

Comment: There is a vast literature on this subject. A good place to start would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_markup

I'd suggest you spend a couple of weeks reading before trying to devise your own solution.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thank you very much. Yes, I understand that the question is not the best, but I didn’t know where to start